# toggle button setOnClickListener can not resolve

Tags: android, onclick, android-studio, listener, onclicklistener

I am new to android programming and i got this from the developer website on how to properly implement this. However when i copy and pasted this into android studio it could not resolve setOnClickListener, setOnCheckedChangeListener, and buttonView.

This is my first time working with toggle buttons and buttons in android and i did a lot of searching about on here before i broke down to ask this. This is a separate button class outside of MainInterface do i need to extend or implement anything special or import anything?

```
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
 import android.net.NetworkInfo;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.CompoundButton;
 import android.widget.ToggleButton;        

 public class Button extends MainInterface {

    ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.BeaconButton);
    toggle.setOnClickListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener());
    toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                // The toggle is enabled
            } else {
                // The toggle is disabled
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Also what is the difference between the above code and the following code. would the following code be applicable for setting listeners?

```
public void onToggleClicked(View view) {
    // Is the toggle on?
    boolean on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();
    if (on) {
        // do something
        }

    } else {
        // set as it was
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you have to use Activity instead of MainInterface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `setOnClickListener` does not accepts `CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()` as a listener thus giving you compile time error.

The method signature for `setOnClickListener`

```
setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener l)
```

**solution:**

Use the default `View.OnClickListener` listener for views to be set in your `ToggleButton`

```
 toggle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

Comment: @castaway2000 make sure you imported this `import android.view.View.OnClickListener;`

Comment: @castaway2000 depends on what are you doing onClick means when you click in your Toogle button you do some action now for `setOnCheckedChangeListener` is when you check or uncheck your `Toogle button`

Comment: `         ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.BeaconButton);
        toggle.OnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){


            }}`


In this both "View v", toggle.OnClickListener can not be resolved and @Overide is not allowed as annotations are not allowed. What are your suggestions? Could i use the bottom code i provided as an alternative?

Comment: import android.view.View.OnClickListener;  andoird studio is telling me that it is unused and not needed

Comment: @castaway2000 you sure?? change this `toggle.OnClickListener` to `asd.setOnClickListener`

Comment: after working with your suggestions a little bit this worked out for me in the end. thank you for clarifying this for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method..

```
this.someToggleButton = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.someToggleButton) ;

    this.someToggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener( new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton toggleButton, boolean isChecked) 
        {
            doSomethingWith(toggleButton, isChecked) ;
        }
    }) ;
```

Comment: this one is a much better description than the website. thanks for helping me clarify this.